# Is there a name for not needing to run an algorithm entirely because you have already started it in advance?

Tags: algorithm, computation

I have a graph algorithm I don't need to run from scratch when invoking a function because I've been tracking the necessary information in advance. The opposite of lazy evaluation, or "reversed memoization", so to say.

Is there a name for this way of processing data?

Comment: I believe you mean like eager algorithms/learning
here some more information about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eager_learning

Comment: I'd say that's basically [Dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

Comment: I heard the term *effective complexity of an algorithm* related to those memoization tricks.

Comment: @rici although dynamic programming implies the idea that the problem can be divided into subproblems, and that subsolutions of an optimal solution to the problem are optimal solutions of the subproblems, and conversely

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think there’s a standardized term for this, but it seems appropriate to say that you’ve been computing the information *incrementally* as more data arrive.

For context, there’s a notion of *incremental algorithms*, which are algorithms that maintain information about a dynamically updated set of values that can change as new data values are added. For example, the “incremental minimum spanning tree problem” is to maintain an MST for a graph as new edges are added in. What you’re describing sounds like it’s in the same ballpark.